# UItableView automaticDimension not working with UIStackView

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uistackview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I want that my `UITableViewCell` calculates properly its height so its bottom matches the `UIStackView` bottom.

I have an understanding that for `UITableView.automaticDimension` to work you need to set all the vertical constraints of the `UITableViewCell` so it can calculate its height.

That's what I'm failing to do. I've made a test project in which I made sure of:

- `tableView.rowHeight` property is set to `UITableView.automaticDimension`.
- To not implement function `heightForRowAt`.
- `TableViewCell` `Row Height` is set to `Automatic` in the xib file.
- All views are constrained vertically.
- To play with `UIStackView` `distribution` property.
- To set the `UIStackView` bottom constraint to the `superView` to `Less Than or Equal` (with this items are too tiny and with `Greater Than or Equal`, or `Equal`, item's height is equal to screen width since they have `aspect ratio` 1:1
- To play with `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority`. In the test all views have default values, for hugging horizontal and vertical 250, and for compression horizontal and vertical 750.

The code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class IBAutomaticDimensionTableViewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.register(
            IBAutomaticDimensionTableViewCell.nib,
            forCellReuseIdentifier: IBAutomaticDimensionTableViewCell.nibName
        )
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
//        view.layoutIfNeeded() Not working with or without it
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: IBAutomaticDimensionTableViewCell.nibName,
            for: indexPath
        ) as! IBAutomaticDimensionTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

The cell's xib file:
[image: The cell's xib file]

Result with `Less Than or Equal` bottom constraint:

[image: Result with Less Than or Equal bottom constraint]

Result with `Greater Than or Equal` or `Equal` bottom constraint:

[image: Result with Greater Than or Equal or Equal bottom constraint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the aspect ratio constraints. It seems that they are prioritizing width over height (that's weird to me since height is a constant value and I would expect for it to be prioritized over a calculated one, but Apple thought differently)

In Android you can specify which one has preference (width or height), I don't know a way here (playing with aspect ratio constraints' relation didn't solve it)

**Replacing aspect ractio constraints for the hardcoded width values (32 first view and 20 for the rest) solved it**